# Was Lore on the Borg renegade ship or on the planet where he was doing his business?

Tags: star-trek, borg, star-trek-data

Something I'm curious about. When the renegade Borg were causing havoc with their attacks on the Enterprise and the brutal fight in the outpost, was Lore heading that ship or was he on the planet doing his business with other renegade Borg drones there?

Comment: good question - nothing in the script seems to indicate either way to me. Crosis seems to, possibly, have some measure of ability to affect Data as well, or there are lingering effects from Onhiaka Three. If I had to guess, given Crosis' interaction w/ Data, I would suspect Lore was not putting himself in the potential cross-hairs of the Enterprise, and thus was safely tucked away in his lair, baiting Data to come to him with expendable Borg

Comment: I disagree on Crosis having an ability to affect Data. He only managed to because he had a doohicky to evoke the temptation on Data.

Comment: ...wouldn't having a doohickey to evoke emotion count as "an ability to affect Data"?

Comment: To be honest, I thought you meant that as a person Crosis had the ability to affect Data.

Comment: But even if you meant in that way, doesn't Lore control them all?

Comment: to a degree - but not completely, only in sense of Lore being a cult/Svengali type leader. As evidenced by Riker's conversation with Hugh. The Borg under Lore are individuals and can make their own choices (and thus can be deceived). Hugh has realized this and broken away. If Lore just outright controlled them, Hugh and his group would also be under Lore's sway